# What is the formula used by .NET chart controls when using a logarithmic scale?

Tags: c#, .net, charts

I'm making a bar chart using .NETs Chart controls with a pretty wide range of values.  The top of the chart (AxisY.Maximum) is 4930 and some of the Y values are:

```
573, 392, 151, 182, 4675, 103, 3100, 432, 326, 53, 3415, 1125, 115...
```

A pretty wide range of values, so I'm setting the chart to use a logarithmic scale with

```
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.IsLogarithmic = true;
```

and

```
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = .1;  //Gives a nice number of lines.
```

That's fine, it works quite well.  What isn't working is I'm trying to figure out the scale of each tick mark on the graph.

Side of the graph looks like this:

[image]

Looking at the .NET object, it says the log base scale is 10, but that doesn't seem to fit at all.  Looks like each tick mark is going up by 25.

Here's why I'm trying to do, each of the bars in the chart have text on them, I'm looking at each one individually and trimming the text if it gets too long.
So something with a Y value of around 125 should only have a few characters of text, but something with a value of 1000 should be allowed about 50 characters (Total length of the screen in characters is about 110).

The formula I've tried using with a log base of 10, works OK, but has a tendency to put in too many characters on low scores.  This is what it looks like:

[image]

My ultimate question is, if I'm looking an individual Y value of a bar (Say 150) how can I tell where on the chart this will fall (e.g. it's 150, so it's above the 126 tick mark and below the 158 tick mark.).

Comment: That looks like a log base 10 scale.  Look at the distance between 100 and 1000, then compare that with 1000 and 10000, I think you'll find they are the same.

Answer (score 1):

So, if I understand your question correctly you want to know how far along the chart a number is.  The answer could be pixels or inches or whatever...we'll call that multiplier `m`.

- 10 should appear at 1*m (log (10) == 1)
- 100 should appear at 2*m (log (100) == 2)

To find where any arbitrary value will appear (I'm using 150 from your example):

`Math.Log10(150) * m`

Which equals `2.18 * m`.

All that's left is for you to figure out what your m is.  I don't have enough info to help you with that.

It may help to use values from the chart to understand why they are there:

- Math.Log10(126) = 2.1
- Math.Log10(158) = 2.2
- Math.Log10(200) = 2.3
- Math.Log10(251) = 2.4

You'll note that they increment along the chart by 1/10 each time.

Comment: I've tried brute force trying to guess the value, say: Math.Log10(y) * m and set M to different values.  What I find is that m = 6 works well at the bottom of the chart, but is inaccurate at the top.  And m = 50 works well at the bottom of the chart, but not the top.

Comment: m is arbitrary.  We're trying to solve for the distance between each tick on the chart, which looks to be about 48 pixels.  So in strict math, the formula should be log10(126) * 22.85 = 50  - but if I apply this to a higher value log10(960) * 22.85  = 68.144 - where I'm actually expecting closer to 500.

Comment: If it's 48px between each tick then it's approximately 480px between the base 10s.  So m = 480.  If your chart starts at 100, Do you find that 1000 is at 480px, and 3981 is at 768px?  I just realized my example assumed you started at 1, whereas your picture starts at 100...Did you account for that?  If not, use `Math.Log10(yourValue) - Math.Log10(100)`